# HTTP Error 406 always on site?

Tags: htaccess

Hello WordPress community,

I am getting http 406 error in my website when ever I tried to change something in my site.
it looks similar like this below line

```
This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 406
```

I tried this in htaccess but the result is same .

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have also disabled the mod security from the cpanel but the result is same.

Can any one help me with this issue ?

Comment: Still no one ??